# Evaluate jquery selector in named callback function only when callback is called

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, callback

I have the following code, which loads div#b into div#a and subsequently does something with div#b:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
                $('#a').load('test2.html', {},
                    // function() {
                        // console.log($('#b').attr('id')); // returns "b"
                        // $('#b').html('content in #b');
                        // console.log('completed');
                    // }
                    fillB()
                );
            });
            function fillB(option=null) {
                console.log($('#b').attr('id'));//returns undefined :(
                $('#b').html('content in #b: '+option);
                console.log('completed');
            }
        </script>
        <div id="a">placeholder</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

where test2.html contains:

```
<div id="b"></div>
```

My objective is to have the callback function (commented out) be a named function fillB() instead, so that I can reuse the code elsewhere. However, when I do this, the selector `$('#b')` is `undefined`.
How can I have the function fillB() execute the selector correctly, when it is called?

**Edit:** I also want to be able to control what parameters are passed to `fillB()`.

Comment: `$('#a').load('test2.html', fillB)`

Comment: `.load("..", func())` calls `func` and passes the *result* as the callback.   `.load("..", func)` passes the function as the callback (without calling it until it's needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this instead. It is much shorter and does the same with fewer places to go wrong

I also changed the vanilla load event to a jQuery one

```
const fillB = () => {
  $('#b').html('content in #b');
};

$(function() {
  $('#a').load('test2.html', fillB);
});
```

Comment: The clue is in `const` and in not adding `()` after `fillB`?

Comment: The clue is the missing () which we do not want to run until after the load. If that does not work, then you will indeed need `$('#a').load('test2.html', () => fillB());` as an anonymous function

Comment: Okay, got it. I have to pass `() => fillB()` in order to not pass any parameters.

Comment: *I have to pass* - no, there are options.   See the code in this answer - it does not pass an anonymous function to setup a callback with no parameters.

Comment: @freedomn-m I'm sorry for the confusion but I realized I simplified my question a bit too much and had to edit it. I do have to pass it like that because I must avoid passing the `this` object as parameter.

Comment: Whatever works for you.   SO is meant to provide questions+answers for future reference.  If you ask "why does `, fillB()` run immediately" and then answer with "I *must* use `() => fillB()`" then it will confuse future readers who may not know the distinction between the various variants.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I have to pass the named callback function in an anonymous one:

```
function() { fillB(); }
```

Comment: No, not necessary. You can call the function directly without the brackets. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77104899/295783) and [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77104842/evaluate-jquery-selector-in-named-callback-function-only-when-callback-is-called/77104899#comment135926799_77104842)

Comment: `.load('..', function() { fillB(); }` is an option (as is `.load('..', () => fillB() )`), but, as noted above, not necessary.  To pass the function (without running it), use `.load('..', fillB)`